# Determine minimizer of variational problem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations

Let $p>3/2 $ and define the energy functional $\mathcal E$ by
$$\mathcal E(\psi) := \int_{\mathbb R^3} G \lvert \psi(x) \rvert^p - Z \frac{\lvert \psi(x) \rvert^2}{\lvert x \rvert} \, dx \quad \forall \psi \in H^1(\mathbb R^d),$$
where $G, Z $ are positive constants. Determine the minimizer of the variational problem
$$E_0 := \inf\{\mathcal E(\psi): \lVert \psi \rVert _2 = 1\}.$$

I don't know how to properly start doing this. I know that I can carry out an ansatz like 
$$\frac{d}{dt}(\psi_0 + t f) = 0$$
if $\psi_0$ is a minimizer, but I wasn't able to use this here in a nice way. I would really appreciate a nice explanation on how to work with this kind of problem.

Comment: First of all, you need to check that your functional is bounded below (which it should be using Cauchy-Schwarz). One of your main problems is that you work on a Frechet Space $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R^3})$. The second problem you face is that your functional offers no easy compactness for the space $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R^3})$ as far as I know. The direct method will therefore be hard to apply. In order to use the Euler-Lagrange equation to characterize a minimizer, you need one to exist. Otherwise, you only get stationary points.

Comment: The only thing that I see is that your functional is invariant with respect to orthogonal transformations i.e. $E(\phi(x))=E(\phi(Qx))$ for $Q \in O(3)$. Maybe applying Colemans/Palais principle might work. See the papers "On the Coleman's principle concerning the stationary points of invariant functionals" or "The principle of symmetric criticality". One of them might contain the answer.

Comment: I think I made a mistake, the infimum should be taken over all $\psi \in H^1(\mathbb R^d)$. Do we have better chances there? I confused it because $C_c1^\infty$ is dense.

Comment: Yes! Definetly! $H^1$ is a Hilberspace (which implies that it is reflexive as well as complete).